# how i can render directly my menu when my local storage is not null?

Tags: reactjs

i wanna render my menu directly when i put something on my localStorage.

basically my render doesn't appeared when i have nothing on my localstorage. When i have something is re rendering but i have to actualise my page.

How i can have my composant menu directly with my redirection ?

```
function App() {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

  let logged = localStorage.getItem("connexion");

  const showNav = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("connexion") != null) {
      return <Menu />;
    } else {
      return <div></div>;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    showNav();
    if (localStorage.getItem("connexion") != null) {
      setLogin(true);
    }
  }, [login]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        {showNav()}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/contact" component={MeContacter} />
          <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/" component={Connexion} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why localStorage but not _Component Props_ or _State_? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `storage` event handler on the `window` object:

First define a state which controlls whether the menu should be showing or not:

```
const [isMenuShowing,setMenuShowing]=useState(false)
```

Now in a useEffect, add the event listener to change `isMenuShowing` whenever localStorage is modified:

```
useEffect(()=>{

    const storageEventHandler=()=>{
             if (localStorage.getItem("connexion") != null) {
             setMenuShowing(true)
         }}


       window.addEventListener("storage",storageEventHandler)

return ()=>{window.removeEventListener(storageEventHandler)}},[])
```

Finally :

```
 return (
<Router>
  <div>
    {isMenuShowing && <Menu/>}
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/contact" component={MeContacter} />
      <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/" component={Connexion} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</Router>
  );
```

**Important!** According to MDN docs, this event fires whenever the change to localStorage is **from another windows**, but i tested it on chrome and it actually worked if the modification was on the same window too.